# Ubuntu Mydomain.pem : Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, ssl

I have a five files in my Webserver(Nginx) folder :

1. cert_www.Mydomain.com.crt
2. prv_www.Mydomain.com.key
3. rootca_www.Mydomain.com.crt
4. subca1_www.Mydomain.com.crt
5. subca2_www.Mydomain.com.crt

i want to combine the crt files. but my commands not working. i'm using cat command. please see the below command.

```
ubuntu@ip:/etc/nginx/ssl$ sudo cat cert_www.Mydomain.com.crt subca1_www.Mydomain.com.crt rootca_www.Mydomain.com.crt > www.Mydomain.com.pem
-bash: www.Mydomain.com.pem: Permission denied
```

I don't understand, not really sure what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the shell redirection applies in your unprivileged shell; it doesn't get the benefit of the `sudo`.

Just get a regular root shell (run `sudo -i`) and then run the command again.  There are trickier ways of doing it (such as piping through `sudo tee`) but it's not worth the hassle for a simple interactive session.

Answer (score 1):

**Explaination:**

You have two "permission contexts". So, your one-line is running with these contexts:

```
(sudo cat cert_www.Mydomain.com.crt subca1_www.Mydomain.com.crt rootca_www.Mydomain.com.crt) (>www.Mydomain.com.pem)

  ^Running with "root" user context                                                            ^Running with "ubuntu" user context
```

**Attention:** When you use '>' it is not running inside sudo "context".

**Solution:**

```
sudo cat cert_www.Mydomain.com.crt subca1_www.Mydomain.com.crt rootca_www.Mydomain.com.crt | sudo tee www.Mydomain.com.pem >/dev/null
```